# submit contact form not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

following is my contact form and i want to sumnit the message

```
<div class="contact-formular">
                <div class="message"></div>
                <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactForm" class="contactform" id="contactForm"  >
                    <div class="one_half element_from_left">
                        <input id="senderName" name="senderName" type="text" class="name required" size="30" value="Name" title="Name" />
                        <input id="senderEmail" name="senderEmail" type="text" class="email required" size="30" value="Email" title="Email" />
                        <input id="senderPhone" name="senderPhone" type="text" class="phone required" size="30" value="Phone" title="Phone" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="one_half last element_from_right">
                        <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="40" rows="4" class="comments" title="Message">Message</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input id="sendMessage" name="send-btn" type="submit" class="send_message submit" value="Send message" />
                </form>

                    <div id="sendingMessage" class="statusMessage">
                        <p>Sending your message. Please wait...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="successMessage" class="statusMessage">
                        <p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="failureMessage" class="statusMessage">
                    <p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="incompleteMessage" class="statusMessage">
                    <p>Please complete all the fields in the form before sending.</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

I am using the following javascript for ajaxing

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

var messageDelay = 2000;  // How long to display status messages (in milliseconds)

// Init the form once the document is ready
$( init );


// Initialize the form

function init() {

  // Hide the form initially.
  // Make submitForm() the form \'s submit handler.
  // Position the form so it sits in the centre of the browser window.
  $('#contactForm').submit( submitForm ).addClass( 'positioned' );

 }




// Submit the form via Ajax

function submitForm() {
  var contactForm = $(this);

  // Are all the fields filled in?

  if ( !$('#senderName').val() || !$('#senderEmail').val() || !$('#message').val() ) {

    // No; display a warning message and return to the form
    $('#incompleteMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
    contactForm.fadeOut().delay(messageDelay).fadeIn();

  } else {

    // Yes; submit the form to the PHP script via Ajax

    $('#sendingMessage').fadeIn();
    contactForm.fadeOut();

    $.ajax( {
      url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
      type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
      data: contactForm.serialize(),
      success: submitFinished
    } );
  }

  // Prevent the default form submission occurring
  return false;
}


// Handle the Ajax response

function submitFinished( response ) {
  response = $.trim( response );
  $('#sendingMessage').fadeOut();

  if ( response == "success" ) {

    // Form submitted successfully:
    // 1. Display the success message
    // 2. Clear the form fields
    // 3. Fade the content back in

    $('#successMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
    $('#senderName').val( "" );
    $('#senderEmail').val( "" );
    $('#senderPhone').val("");
    $('#message').val( "" );

    $('#content').delay(messageDelay+500).fadeTo( 'slow', 1 );

  } else {

    // Form submission failed: Display the failure message,
    // then redisplay the form
    $('#failureMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
    $('#contactForm').delay(messageDelay+500).fadeIn();
  }
}
</script>
```

But after i hit the submit button it gets struck on "Sending your message. Please wait..."

Please help me out to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
 $.ajax( {
      url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
      type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
      data: contactForm.serialize(),
      success: submitFinished
    } );
```

to this-

```
$.ajax( {
      url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
      type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
      data: contactForm.serialize(),
      success: function(result){
        submitFinished(result);
       }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for replying ; i tried it but now the message is "There was a problem sending your message. Please try again"

Comment: @user2963346 That means your ajax call is failing.Check Network tab under console to find the HTTP status code to find the reason for failure.

Comment: still the message is" sending message....... ",, actually that message was from local host,,

Comment: There may be multiple reasons for failure.You may have not access to the server where you are posting or the server is not replying due to some reason.For that we need the HTTP code to verify.Try checking the url and type parameter by an alert.If you are submitting the whole form it is better to hard-code the type parameter as "POST".

Comment: actually i have used the same method earlier on same hosting server , and it worked fine but now .......   But still thank i ll try wat u said

Comment: ,,,i am getting this error [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 1108ms] ReferenceError: prettyPrint is not defined